# Word VBA - Force Document to Load New Timestamp before Macro executes

Tags: excel, vba, ms-word, powerpoint, timing

I have a timing issue in Word VBA. I am trying to open and update thousands of documents, each one with 2 timestamps in the footer that update upon opening to the date and time the document was recently opened.

My macro has code to remove these timestamps. This code works, but I am running into a problem: **the timestamps do not have enough time to load in before the macro executes when looping through hundreds of documents**, so they are not removed.

The function to open and close the documents is this:

```
Sub ProcessFile(ByVal f As String, ByVal m As String)
    Dim doc As Document
    Documents.Open FileName:=f, AddToRecentFiles:=False
    ActiveDocument.Repaginate
    Application.Run m
    ActiveDocument.Close SaveChanges:=True
    Set doc = Nothing
End Sub
```

The code I have put in my macro that attempts to force the document to load is this:

```
WaitUntil = Now() + TimeValue("00:00:05")
Do While Now < WaitUntil
    DoEvents
Loop
```

Which does not work. **I just need a way to give the document a certain amount of time to load its content in before running the macro**

Comment: Please try to add `ActiveDocument.Fields.Update` before waiting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess it is for the same project as your last post.

- Please try to add `ActiveDocument.Fields.Update` before waiting

OR

- If the date is a field in footers, you can try to remove it with below code.

**Note:** please backup your documents before testing.

```vb
Sub DeleteDateFields()
    Dim section As section
    Dim footer As Range
    Dim field As field
    For Each section In ActiveDocument.Sections
        Set footer = section.Footers(wdHeaderFooterPrimary).Range
        For Each field In footer.Fields
            If field.Type = wdFieldDate Then
                field.Delete
                MsgBox "Found and deleted a date field in the footer."
            End If
        Next field
    Next section
End Sub
```